# How to select rows of a table having missing records in each upload

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Please could someone help with a MYSQL Select query wherein I update the table at two different intervals (01/01/2019 and 02/01/2019) in the given example and I should be able to trace the missing updates from the previous upload (ie 01/01/2019)

```
S.No    Emp Name    Update Date
1   Test 1  01/01/19
2   Test 2  01/01/19
3   Test 3  01/01/19
4   Test 1  02/01/19
5   Test 2  02/01/19
```

In the above example, I am expecting the result of the query to be

```
3, Test 3, 01/01/2019
```

for the MYSQL query syntax run?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the rows with missing updates with NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.*
from tablename
where 
  t.updatedate = '2019-01-01'
  and not exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where empname = t.empname and date = '2019-01-02'
  )
```

Comment: Thanks forpas. Will give it a try and revert.. much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows that are updated on one day but not the next:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.empname = t.empname and
                        t2.date = t.date + interval 1 day
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.date = t.date + interval 1 day
             );
```

The first clause checks that nothing exists on the next day for the `empname`.  The second checks that something does exist, to prevent returning everything on the most recent day.

You can add a `where` clause to limit the outer query to one or more days of interest.